# write не записывает в файл

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

```
import random

nmb = open("nmb.txt", "w")

percen = random.random()*100
percent = round(percen, 1)  

nmb.write(str(percent))


nmb.close()
```

Файл пустой, он его даже не очищает, хотя "w" должен

Comment: Проверил, код рабочий. @Дорсау, а если указать полный путь, будет перезаписывать файл?

Comment: gil9red намекает, что файл таки создается, но не в том месте, где вы ожидаете

Comment: Выдает ошибку: python "D:\pyt_prjct\hai.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\pyt_prjct\hai.py", line 2, in <module>
    nmb = open("D:\pyt_prjct\nmb.txt", "w")
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'D:\\pyt_prjct\nmb.txt'

Comment: Добавьте `r` к пути: `r"D:\pyt_prjct\nmb.txt"` иначе `\n` будет восприниматься как перенос строки.

Comment: Все равно: python "D:\pyt_prjct\hai.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\pyt_prjct\hai.py", line 2, in <module>
    nmb = open("D:\pyt_prjct\rnmb.txt", "w")
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'D:\\pyt_prjct\rnmb.txt'

Comment: Не нужно r в середину строки втыкать, только перед самой строкой (перед кавычкой). `\r` который у вас получился, это тоже специальный символ - возврат каретки. Советую ознакомиться: [Работа со строками в Python: литералы](https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/stroki-literaly-strok.html)

Comment: Спасибо, заработало

Answer (score 0):

Используйте полный путь к папке для записи файла:

```
import random

nmb = open(r"C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\nmb.txt", "w")

percen = random.random()*100
percent = round(percen, 1)

nmb.write(str(percent))

nmb.close()
```

Если же вы указываете путь к файлу как "nmb.txt", файл будет создан в текущей директории консоли с которой запускается скрипт. Тоесть если запускать скрипт как показано на скриншоте, файл будет создан в папке: C:\Windows\System32\nmb.txt
[image]